# Как обозначить пробел в поиске элементов, что бы их можно было посчитать?

Tags: python

```
print('Введите строку:')
s=input()
a=0
for i in range(0,len(s)):
    n=s.find ( ' ' ) # возможно ли как-то тут обозначить пробел?
    if n>=0:
        a=a+1
print(a)
```

Comment: Зачем Вам цикл, если Вы не используете переменную итерирования?

Comment: Мне нужно посчитать количество слов в строке)

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы посчитать количество символов, воспользуйтесь строковым методом `count`

```
>>> s = "a dog is a cat. Its awful!"
>>> s.count(" ")
6
```

Метод `find` находит индекс первого вхождения подстроки. Проще говоря, находит позицию, на которой находится первый пробел. Он не считает символы.